# fetch header values from ag-grid in selenium

Tags: selenium, ag-grid

in my website, i have an ag-grid and it loads data only on scrolling; how to get the whole header value and assert it?

i have tried as below and it is working fine for page 1 and i will get new headers once i scroll. how to get the second part of headers?

```html
String[] expectedCol={"Subject","Date Received","Status","Tag","Assigned To","Sender Name","Receiver Name"};
         List<WebElement> column=drvobj.findElements(By.xpath("//div [@class='ag-header-cell ag-header-cell-sortable']"));
            for (int i=0;i<column.size();i++)
                for (int j=0;j<expectedCol.length;j++){
                    System.out.println(column.get(i).getText());
                    System.out.println(expectedCol[j]);
                    if(column.get(i).getText().equals(expectedCol[j])){
                        System.out.println("Text Matched");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("Text Not Matched");
                    }
                    i++;
                }
```

Comment: Instead of getting all headers. you can try with scrolling one page at a time and compare it.

Comment: ok..if you can you give me a sample it will be helpful